# IOS Subview doesn't always appears

Tags: ios, xcode, subview, appdelegate

I have an app, with a lot of views and subviews.

In my app delegate, I open a subview each time I receive a notification.
I made a lot of tests :
- the notifications are always received well. 
- the subview is always well created, it's never at nil.

But after a notification or two, the subviews do not show again, even if they exist and are well created in memory.

I think I am doing something wrong with the memory and I probably misunderstood something with the view hierarchy.

Here is the code that create and add the subview :

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) ViewControllerNewOrder *sub;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
sub = [[ViewControllerDriverNewOrder alloc] init];
sub = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerNewOrder"];
sub.view.frame = self.initialViewController.view.bounds;
[self.initialViewController.view addSubview:sub.view];
```

Thank you for your time and your help !

Comment: You might want to give [iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer](https://github.com/glock45/iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer) a try, so you can see where your subviews are.

Comment: I will. But is there a way to clean the stack of views ?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem but...depending on whether or not you're using ARC, your alloc/init line of code is either a waste of time or a memory leak.

Comment: I am using ARC, I added this lines because I thought that maybe the problem came from that. But your opinion is way more logical and I think you are right. I am deleting it now.

Comment: As expected, it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line saved my life :

```
[self.window.rootViewController.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Then I added the method removeFromSuperView to all the views I needed to clear.
Of course, you will need, like me, to think about where you place this line.

Thanks ;)